# Передача данных в шаблон Flask

Tags: javascript, python, flask

Делаю веб-приложение на Flask и возникла необходимость передать в шаблон список из словарей, а в одном из значений словаря находится список объектов Word. При прохождении по данному списку и внесения его данный в шаблон возникла проблема `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable`
на строке

```
{% for word in item["words"] %}
```

вот весь код

```
var data_list = [];

{% for item in data %}
    var dict = {};
    dict["rus_word"] = '{{ item['rus_word'] }}';
    dict["img_path"] = '{{ item['img_path'] }}';
    dict["eng_word"] = '{{ item['eng_word'] }}';
    dict["card_type"] = '{{ item['card_type'] }}';

    {% for word in item["words"] %}
        alert('{{ word }}');
        words.push('{{ word.eng_word }}');
    {%endfor%}
    dict["words"] = words;
    }
    data_list.push(dict);
{% endfor %}
```

Почему-то на этапе перебора слов он не понимает, что это список.
Вот data, который передается в шаблон. word_list - выборка из базы данных, список объектов Word

```
data = list()
all_words = models.Word.query.order_by(func.random()).limit(10).all()

for word in all_words:
    rand = randint(0, 1)
    word_list = models.Word.query.filter_by(theme_id=word.theme_id).order_by(func.random()).all()  

    word_dict = {
        "rus_word": word.rus_word,
        "img_path": word.img_path,
        "card_type": rand,
        "words": word_list,
    }
    data.append(word_dict)
```

Причем не работает именно тогда, когда я прохожусь циклом по `item["words"]`, когда же обращаюсь к списку словарей таким образом `data[0]["words"][0]` и тд, оно выводит объект слова и можно обращаться к полям

Comment: Код явно не весь, потому что содержимое data вы не показали

Comment: Это всё ещё не очень похоже на полное содержимое data. Покажите полностью как формируется data на всех стадиях

Comment: И вообще составьте [mcve] чтобы не гадать

Comment: Добавила полный код data

Comment: Шаблонизировать js-код - очень плохая идея. Выносите его отдельно и передавайте туда данные отдельно.